# Event Sourcing: multiple events vs a single "StatusChanged"

Tags: event-sourcing

Assuming the common "Order" aggregate, my view of events is that each should be representative of the command that took place. E.g. `OrderCreated`, `OrderePicked`, `OrderPacked`, `OrderShipped`.
Applying these events in the *aggregate* changes the *status* of the order accordingly.

The problem:
I have a *projector* that lists all orders in the system and their statuses. So it consumes the events, and like with the aggregate "apply" method, it implements the logic that changes the status of the order.
So now the logic exists in two places, which is... not good.

A solution to this is to replace all the above events with a single `StatusChanged` event that contains a property with the new status.
Pros: both aggregate and projectors just need to handle one event type, and set the status to what's in that event. Zero logic.
Cons: the list of events is now very implicit. Instead of getting a list of WHAT HAPPENED (created, packed, shipped, etc.), we now have a list of the status changes events.

How do you prefer to approach this?

Note: this is not the full list of events. other events contain other properties, so clearly they don't belong to this problem. the problem is with events that don't contain any info, just change the status of an order.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's better to have more finer-grained events, because this preserves context (and means that you don't have to write logic to reconstruct the context in your consumers).

You typically will have at most one projector which is duplicating your aggregate's event handler.  If its purpose is actually to duplicate the aggregate's event handler (e.g. update a datastore which facilitates cross-aggregate querying), you may want to look at making that explicit as a means of making the code DRY (e.g. function-as-value, strategy pattern...).

For the other projectors you write (and there will be many as you go down the CQRS/ES road), you're going to be ignoring events that aren't interesting to that projection and/or doing radically different things in response to the events you don't ignore.  If you go down the road of coarse events (CRUD being about the limit of coarseness: a `StatusChanged` event is just the "U" in CRUD), you're setting yourself up for either:

- duplicating the aggregate's event handling/reconstruction in the projector
- carrying `oldState` and `newState` in the event (viz. just saying `StatusChanged { newState }` isn't sufficient)

before you can determine what changed and the code for determining whether a change is interesting will probably be duplicated and more complex than the aggregate's event-handling code.

The coarser the events, the greater the likelihood of eventually having more duplication, less understandability, and worse performance (or higher infrastructure spend).

Answer (score 0):

> So now the logic exists in two places, which is... not good.

Not necessarily a problem.  If the logic is static, then it really doesn't matter very much.  If the logic is changing, but you can coordinate the change (ex: both places are part of the same deployment bundle), then its fine.

Sometimes this means introducing an extra layer of separation between your "projectors" and the consumers - ex: something that is tightly coupled to the aggregate watching the events, and copying status changes to some (logical) cache where other processes can read the information.  Thus, you preserve the autonomy of your component without compromising your event stream.

Another possibility to consider is that we're allowed to produce more than one event from a command - so you could have both an OrderPicked event and a StatusChanged event, and then use your favorite filtering method for subscribers only interested in status changes.

In effect, we've got two different sets of information to track to remember later - inputs (information in the command, information copied from local caches), and also things we have calculated from those inputs, prior state, and the business policies that are now in effect.

So it may make sense to separate those expressions of information *anyway*.

---

If event sourcing is a good approach for the problems you are solving, then you are probably working on problems that are pretty important to the business, where specialization matters (otherwise, licensing an off the shelf product and creating adapters would be more cost effective).  In which case, you should probably be expecting to invest in thinking deeply about the different trade offs you need to make, rather than hoping for a one-size-fits-all solution.